# Fetch put api with x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: reactjs, fetch, put

I want fetch a put API. I did test with postman and it works. I just don't know why my code don't work. I want to use x-www-form-urlencoded with a body has 1 param 'isRaining':true. The url is http://thutrongtts.ml:3000/states. It accidentally works once but after i edit a little bit, it never works again although i tried fix it

```js
toggleRaining(){
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('isRaining', true);
        var options = {
            'method': 'PUT',
            'headers': {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "cache-control": "no-cache"
            },
            'body': formData
        };
        fetch('http://thutrongtts.ml:3000/states',options).then(resp => resp.json());
    }
```

And this is postman test code

```js
var qs = require("querystring");
var http = require("http");

var options = {
  "method": "PUT",
  "hostname": [
    "thutrongtts",
    "ml"
  ],
  "port": "3000",
  "path": [
    "states"
  ],
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "73bd58f4-bbf6-44d9-9d01-2a3e8ff9746a"
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
  });
});

req.write(qs.stringify({ isRaining: 'true', undefined: undefined }));
req.end();
```

Comment: If you add `.catch(error => console.error(error));` to the fetch, do you see an error in the console? Do you see an error in the Network tab of the Developer Tools?

Comment: i did and i don't see any error in the console. It just return back the states without any change